# InternalsVisibleTo is not working for wpf application

Tags: wpf, data-binding, internalsvisibleto

I have the [assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("GuiAssembly")] set in the other assembly but when wpf binding occurs on a class that lives in the other assembly, it throws an exception because of the property in that class being internal.

I know this works with other applications but not sure why it is not working with this particular WPF app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that everything that WPF binds to needs to be public.

Comment: It looks like wpf doesn't care about assembly attributes. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: I have the same problem :(